# Can't ALTER TABLE in ACCESS 2012

Tags: sql, ms-access, alter-table

I'm trying to alter the table of an access database. I keep getting a syntax error for something I think should be pretty simple.

Here is what I tried to do and the error I am getting. [image]

Comment: Get in the habit of pushing that "Help" button.

Answer (score 1):

yes you have syntax error as what access tells you, try this one

```
ALTER TABLE EMP_2 ADD COLUMN EMP_PCT NUMBER(4);
ALTER TABLE EMP_2 ADD COLUMN PROJ_NUM CHAR(3);
```

the syntax

```
ALTER TABLE table {ADD {COLUMN field type[(size)] [NOT NULL] [CONSTRAINT index] |
ALTER COLUMN field type[(size)] |
CONSTRAINT multifieldindex} |
DROP {COLUMN field I CONSTRAINT indexname}}
```

- [ALTER TABLE statement](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/alter-table-statement-HA001231431.aspx)

Comment: @Batman try this `ALTER TABLE EMP_2 ADD COLUMN EMP_PCT NUMBER;`

Comment: [MS ACCESS NUMBER DataType (*click here*)](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-data-types-and-field-properties-HA010233292.aspx#BM2g)

Comment: The SQL data type is NUMERIC, not NUMBER.

Comment: Yea it only works work I leave it blank, if i assign a size it wont work.

Comment: @Catcall are you sure? it's on the documentation.

Comment: @Catcall the question is tagged with `MS Access` not `SQL Server`

Comment: Access says number and not numeric :/

Comment: @KuyaJohn: I said "SQL", not "SQL Server". [ANSI SQL and Access SQL data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195814.aspx)

Comment: Are you saying I should change it to Numeric and not Number?